# Does Spring-data support RepositoryMetadata extension?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-cloud

I'm adding custom behavior to all repositories (JPA module) to add our own Query api/syntax. We want to externalize from the code so it can be changed at runtime (currently these are added as custom annotations to the domain class).

Examples:

- Data security by setting dynamic role/column security matrix (roleA can access i.e. addition of filters only a subset of rows, roleB has some sensitive attributes masked,...)
- Enabled/Disabled functionality to allow for preloading of code to prod/or limited rollout.
- Overriding schema name (allowing code to be pointed at different target sandbox tables for various testing efforts)

In my Repository Impl class I could read this configuration and store it as attributes here but I was wondering if it would make more sense (and if supported) to extend the Spring Data domain class meta data (in think this is the RepositoryMetadata class).

Thanks
Mark

Comment: Would you mind re-reading and then re-writing your question? I am working on Spring Data and totally do not get what you're asking. Which store module are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry for the conflusion hopefully this is better. If not, maybe a you could state the role and visibility of the RepositoryMetadata class - can it like the Repository be customized to add addition behaviors/functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a couple of classes and methods you want to look at:

- `RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepositoryInformation(…)` if you want to hook into repository metadata.
- `JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(…)` if you want to hook into entity metadata. This is what the repository implementation gets handed to work on.

I think the latter is the most interesting to you. For example the MongoDB module customizes it to allow Spring Expression language in the `@Document` annotation's attribute `collectionName` to dynamically calculate the collection to interact with on each store interaction.

I am not sure how good this works with JPA though as you seem to want to change things that are not really under Spring Data's control but rather evaluated by the persistence provider. To e.g. switch the schema you'd probably rather want to tackle the `DataSource` definition, different table mappings, you'd need to customize on the persistence provider level etc.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking into the mongo implementation to gain a deeper understanding. I'll try and post back some materials to this for future seekers of knowledge.